# Expo icons shows as question mark (?)

Tags: react-native

I use testflight to test my app on real device but the icons shows as question mark but when i test the app using expo app(on the same device) it works fine. It also works fine on simulator and android real device.

```
import { FontAwesome, Ionicons, AntDesign, Entypo, Feather, Foundation } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Icon, Button, List, ListItem } from 'native-base'
```

**FOR TESTING** Purpose I used all these icons to check which one works but all of them shows as question mark

```
            <List>
                <ListItem>
                    <Icon name="cart" />
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <Ionicons name="ios-home" />
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <AntDesign name="stepforward" />
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <Foundation name="alert" />
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <Entypo name="credit" />
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <Feather name="shuffle" />
                </ListItem>
            </List>
```